# New ABAP syntax instead of COLLECT

Tags: abap, internal-tables

Currently, I have this coding, and it works perfectly fine:

```
      TYPES: BEGIN OF tty_ekpo,
               ebeln TYPE ebeln,
               ebelp TYPE ebelp,
             END OF tty_ekpo.
      DATA: lt_ekpo TYPE TABLE OF tty_ekpo,
            ls_ekpo LIKE LINE OF lt_ekpo.
      LOOP AT gt_loopdata ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_collect>).
        ls_ekpo-ebeln = <fs_collect>-ebeln.
        ls_ekpo-ebelp = <fs_collect>-ebelp.
        COLLECT ls_ekpo INTO lt_ekpo.
      ENDLOOP.
```

I want to do the same with the new syntax, is it possible?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this one:

```
lt_ekpo = VALUE #( FOR GROUPS ebelnebelp OF <ls_collect> IN gt_lopdata
                   GROUP BY ( ebeln = <ls_collect>-ebeln
                              ebelp = <ls_collect>-ebelp )
                   ASCENDING WITHOUT MEMBERS ( ebelnebelp ) ).
```

Comment: ABAP documentation: [FOR GROUPS ... GROUP BY](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenfor_groups_of.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Well, I disagree with the Joszsef variant, because addition `WITHOUT MEMBERS` produces all group key values, it does **NOT** sum numeric fields automatically alike `COLLECT`. You need additional actions for this.

Here is the enhanced Joszef's variant that fits your needs and collects NETWR field:

```
  TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_ekpo,
             ebeln TYPE ebeln,
             ebelp TYPE ebelp,
             netwr TYPE ekpo-netwr,
           END OF ty_ekpo,
           tty_ekpo TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_ekpo WITH EMPTY KEY.
  DATA: it_ekpo TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ty_ekpo WITH UNIQUE KEY ebeln ebelp.

DATA(lt1_ekpo) = VALUE tty_ekpo(
                 FOR GROUPS <group_key> OF <g> IN it_ekpo GROUP BY ( ebeln = <g>-ebeln ebelp = <g>-ebelp )
                 LET coll_line = REDUCE #( INIT line TYPE ty_ekpo FOR <m> IN GROUP <group_key>
                                           NEXT line-ebeln = <m>-ebeln line-ebelp = <m>-ebelp line-netwr = line-netwr + <m>-netwr )
                                 IN ( coll_line ) ) .
```

Another flavor based on two REDUCEs:

```
DATA(lt2_ekpo) = REDUCE tty_ekpo( INIT cline = VALUE tty_ekpo( )
                 FOR GROUPS <group_key> OF <g> IN it_ekpo GROUP BY ( ebeln = <g>-ebeln ebelp = <g>-ebelp )
                 NEXT cline = VALUE #( BASE cline ( ebeln = <group_key>-ebeln ebelp = <group_key>-ebelp
                                                    netwr = REDUCE netwr( INIT val TYPE netwr
                                                                          FOR wa IN
                                                                          FILTER #( it_ekpo WHERE ebeln = <group_key>-ebeln AND ebelp = <group_key>-ebelp )
                                                                          NEXT val = val + wa-netwr ) ) ) ).
```

I see that in your original post you also do not make summarizing, you just collecting key fields into table. If this is what you need, Joszef snippet is OK. Just to notice that `COLLECT` does more than that.

Comment: I only need `ebeln` and `ebelp` for FOR ALL ENTRIES.

Comment: Well, then Joszef's variant is OK

Comment: If we have a MATNR field in this table - and it is the same for all lines grouped together by ebeln and ebelp - how do we transfer it in the result table? Currently the field remains empty.

Comment: @kdobrev for the 1st variant you should extend the `ty_ekpo` type and transfer it from itab in the NEXT statement like this `NEXT line-matnr = <m>-matnr line-ebeln = <m>-ebeln line-ebelp = .. `

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question the result will be something line this:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_ekpo,
         ebeln TYPE ebeln,
         ebelp TYPE ebelp,
         netwr TYPE ekpo-netwr,
         matnr type ekpo-matnr,
       END OF ty_ekpo,
       tty_ekpo TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_ekpo WITH EMPTY KEY.


DATA: it_ekpo TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ty_ekpo WITH UNIQUE KEY ebeln ebelp.
DATA(lt1_ekpo) = VALUE tty_ekpo(
             FOR GROUPS <group_key> OF <g> IN it_ekpo GROUP BY ( ebeln = <g>-ebeln ebelp = <g>-ebelp )
             LET coll_line = REDUCE #( INIT line TYPE ty_ekpo FOR <m> IN GROUP <group_key>
                                       NEXT line-ebeln = <m>-ebeln 
                                            line-ebelp = <m>-ebelp 
                                            line-netwr = line-netwr + <m>-netwr
                                            line-matnr = <m>-matnr )
                             IN ( coll_line ) ) .
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't deserve a [`collect`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcollect.htm) whose main interest is to sum numbers, and your internal table doesn't contain numbers (only two character-like fields `ebeln` and `ebelp`).

Your example removes the duplicates, it could be possibly equivalent to a `sort` and `delete adjacent duplicates`, or to an `insert` into an internal table with a unique key.

The term "new syntax" is unclear because each version brings a new syntax, but based on your own answer, you mean the use of [Constructor Expressions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expressions.htm) which appeared in 2013 with ABAP 7.40.

In your case, there's no interest to use Constructor Expressions because it will just be more complex to understand and won't give a better performance.

Remember that `collect` is not obsolete, except that you should use sorted/hashed tables instead of standard tables as explained in the "hints" of the `collect` documentation (ABAP 7.58):

> *The statement COLLECT is not suitable for standard tables and should no longer be used for them. COLLECT can be used for sorted tables and hashed tables without any problems since these, unlike standard tables, always have their own stable key administration that can be exploited by COLLECT*

Comment: COLLECT is not only faster than SORT + DAD, it uses also less memory, especially if there are many duplicates in the keys or there are many columns beside the keys. Very often COLLECT was the solution for an out-of-memory dump

Comment: @András I agree. I don't recommend SORT, I'm explaining what COLLECT does in the example you have given.