# Is it possible to GROUP multiple columns in END AT statement?

Tags: abap

I have internal table `lt_stock` with following rows:

```
WERKS
LGORT
MATNR
QUANTITY
```

I want to group WERKS LGORT and MATNR and add the QUANTITY.

I have done this using 2 loops:

```
LOOP AT lt_stock INTO ls_stock.

  MOVE-CORRESPONDING ls_stock TO ls_stock_key.
  CONCATENATE ls_stock-werks ls_stock-lgort ls_stock-matnr INTO ls_stock_key-key.
  APPEND ls_stock_key TO lt_stock_key.

ENDLOOP.

LOOP AT lt_stock_key INTO ls_stock_key.

  AT END OF key.
    SUM.
    APPEND ls_stock_key TO lt_stock_calculated.
  ENDAT.

 ENDLOOP.
```

Is it possible to do this using a single LOOP?
(Example: `AT END OF werks, lgort, matnr`)

Comment: `SUM` is obsolete, and concerning `AT END OF`, SAP [says](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapat_itab.htm) (since 7.40): "If possible, the use of the addition GROUP BY is recommended, since the grouping does not depend on the structure of the lines and the processing order in this case."

Comment: Why just not use COLLECT statement since you have only key and quantity fields? Here is the same question and some examples with alternatives to it with new group processing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920458/new-abap-syntax-instead-of-collect

Comment: @astentx but I used a LOOP just to create the key and that was actually the problem. I wanted to see if it is possible to only use one LOOP.

Comment: @OvidiuPocnet You've used a loop to generate a key, but why? Just collect or group by in that loop, I've provided a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example based on `LOOP...GROUP BY`:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_stock,
        werks TYPE werks_d,
        lgort TYPE lgort_d,
        matnr TYPE matnr,
        qty  TYPE volum,
       END OF ty_stock,
       tty_stock TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_stock WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY primary_key COMPONENTS werks lgort matnr.

DATA: lt_input TYPE tty_stock.
DATA(out) = cl_demo_output=>new( ).

lt_input = VALUE #( ( werks = 1000 lgort = 100 matnr = '10130101'  qty = 40 )
                    ( werks = 1000 lgort = 120 matnr = '10140101'  qty = 150 )
                    ( werks = 1000 lgort = 130 matnr = '10150101'  qty = 300 )
                    ( werks = 1000 lgort = 130 matnr = '10150101'  qty = 100 )
                    ( werks = 1000 lgort = 140 matnr = '10140101'  qty = 200 )
                    ( werks = 1000 lgort = 140 matnr = '10140101'  qty = 180 )
                    ( werks = 1000 lgort = 150 matnr = '10190101'  qty = 120 )
                    ( werks = 1000 lgort = 130 matnr = '10190101'  qty = 200 )
                    ( werks = 1000 lgort = 120 matnr = '10140101'  qty = 300 )
                    ( werks = 1000 lgort = 200 matnr = '10170101'  qty = 500 )
                  ).

DATA: qty TYPE volum.
LOOP AT lt_input ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_inp>) USING KEY primary_key GROUP BY ( werks = <fs_inp>-werks lgort = <fs_inp>-lgort matnr = <fs_inp>-matnr ) REFERENCE INTO DATA(stock).
  LOOP AT GROUP stock ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_member>).
    qty =  qty + <fs_member>-qty.
  ENDLOOP.
  out->write( stock->lgort && '/' && stock->matnr && ` qty:  ` && qty ).
  CLEAR qty.
ENDLOOP.

out->display( ).
```

By replacing `out->write( )` with `APPEND` you can construct the new totals internal table instead of displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible, but the standard way it to use the three fields (from your example) directly:

```
AT END OF matnr.
    SUM.
...
ENDAT.
```

The prerequisite is that werks, lgort and matnr are the three first fields of the internal table and the table is SORTed.

If you want to do it with a separate field (like in your example), the newly defined field (key) has to be the very first field in the internal table (this is a prerequisite for LOOP ... AT ... ENDAT actions) and the table also has to be SORTed.