# Get total without LOOP based on SAP system table

Tags: sum, abap

I am trying to summarise specific fields in my table that are based on a system table ekbe. Here is how I started:

```
REPORT zz_program3.
TABLES: ekbe.

TYPES: BEGIN OF tt_mati1,
ebeln LIKE ekbe-ebeln,
ebelp LIKE ekbe-ebelp,
bewtp LIKE ekbe-bewtp,
bwart LIKE ekbe-bwart,
menge LIKE ekbe-menge,
suma1 TYPE i,
END OF tt_mati1.

DATA: lt_mati1 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tt_mati1 WITH KEY elebn ebelp.

SELECT *
FROM ekbe
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_mati1
WHERE ( bewtp = 'E' AND bwart = '101' ).
```

Now, I want to sum all fields that will occur, for example:

| EBELN | EBELP | BEWTP | BWART | MENGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 450001122 | 01 | E | 101 | 5,000 |
| 450001122 | 01 | E | 101 | 1,000 |
| 450001122 | 01 | E | 101 | 1,000 |
| 450001122 | 02 | E | 101 | 1,000 |
| 450001122 | 02 | E | 101 | 2,000 |

And I would like to have something like this:

| EBELN | EBELP | BEWTP | BWART | MENGE | SUMA1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 450001122 | 01 | E | 101 | 5,000 | 7,000 |
| 450001122 | 01 | E | 101 | 1,000 | 7,000 |
| 450001122 | 01 | E | 101 | 1,000 | 7,000 |
| 450001122 | 02 | E | 101 | 1,000 | 3,000 |
| 450001122 | 02 | E | 101 | 2,000 | 3,000 |

I know I have to use FOR GROUPS and REDUCE functions but unfortunately I do not know how to implement this in internal table based on system table.

Can anyone help me with solving?

Comment: The ABAP documentation and the Web is full of examples, so please try to search a little bit. You may start with [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenfor_grouping_abexas.htm).

Comment: You can do this with a GROUP BY clause in your SQL statement. I could show you how, but I would need to know which field of the table you want to sum up.

Comment: also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920458/new-abap-syntax-instead-of-collect/57937966#57937966

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use REDUCE or FOR GROUPS for this. You can do grouping within your SQL statement by using a GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT 
  ebeln,
  ebelp
  SUM( menge ) AS menge,
  SUM( dmbtr ) AS suma1,
FROM ekbe
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_mati1
WHERE ( bewtp = 'E' AND bwart = '101' )
GROUP BY ebeln, ebelp.
```

This will take all rows with the same values in EBELN and EBELP and crunch them into one row each with the sum of their MENGE and DMBTR.